# plugin.xml for custom Phonegap 3 plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I must be missing something. I am trying to convert my existing Phonegap plugins to be installable with the CLI. My problem is that none of the source files or frameworks are getting copied into the platform folder and my config.xml is not getting updated with the feature. I have seen other SO questions on this but none of those have helped me.

plugin.xml

```
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
    id="com.test.scanner"
    version="1.0.0">
    <name>Scanner</name>

   <js-module src="www/scanner-plugin.js" name="scanner-plugin">
       <clobbers target="plugins.scanner" />
   </js-module>

   <platform name="ios">
       <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
           <feature name="Scanner">
               <param name="ios-package" value="Scanner"/>
           </feature>
       </config-file>

       <header-file src="src/ScannerSDK.h" />
       <header-file src="src/Scanner.h" />
       <source-file src="src/Scanner.m" />
       <framework src="src/libScannerSDK.a" />
   </platform>
</plugin>
```

I run the command

```
$ phonegap local plugin add ~/Dev/Cordova/Plugins/ios/Scanner
```

and it says it installs fine. Then I build the project using the CLI but my config.xml is not updated and none of my .m .h .a files are in the project (though xcode thinks they should be there). The js file is there and the cordova_plugins.js file is updated. I am seeing the changes for config.xml and such in the ios.json file in the plugins folder but they are never propagated to the actual project.

My file structure is

```
Scanner
   /plugin.xml
   /src
     /ScannerSDK.h
     /Scanner.h
     /Scanner.m
     /libScannerSDK.a
   /www
     /scanner-plugin.js
```

I have tried changing file permissions, Xcode open and closed, removing all traces of the plugin and starting over, but so far to no avail.

To recap: src files are not being copied into the platform folder, and the platform config.xml is not getting updated.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you made any headway on this? I have the same issue, but what I've been doing is manually updating the platform specific config.xml and dropping the files in.  The problem is if you ever run the build command, it will delete those entries. I wish you could override that.

Comment: Yes and no. I guess the plugins are really meant to work with github and the like. Try (if you can) uploading your plugin to a github repo and see if things don't start working. My problem is that I cannot host my plugins on any public domain, so I thought to try with a private git install on a cloud space. I'll update if I ever get things to work. Side note: I updated to 3.1 and I have not been able to get it to work at all with unhosted plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the plugin.xml file and rerunning the command?

Even though I did not have exactly the same problem with you as my source files were being downloaded to my project, when I made changes to my plugin.xml file they were not being propagated to the project's plugin.xml file and the files/references were not being updated. However, when I deleted the local project's plugin.xml file and run plugin add again, the files/references were updated. Maybe your initial plugin.xml did not have references to your source files and now that you updated it the changes are not propagated to your local file.